# Linq datatable to get unique rows and their count

Tags: linq, datatable

i have data table like :

country

China
India
Thailand
India
china
china
Thailand
Hong kong
India

can get my output as shown below using LINQ

Country    Count
India       3
China       2
Thailand    2
Hong kong   1

Comment: Have you looked at LINQ's `GroupBy` extension method?  If you try that and run into trouble, post what you've tried and we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben Allred pointed out, what you're likely looking for is the LINQ `GroupBy`method.

Using query syntax, it may look something like this:

```
    var query = from tuple in table
                group tuple by tuple.Country into g
                select new { Country = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

`query` now contains an IEnumerable collection of anonymous objects which have as members the string `Country` and the integer `Count` representing the number of occurrences of that country in the table.

You can now of course iterate over these objects as such:

```
     foreach (var item in query)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Country : {0} - Count : {1}", item.Country, item.Count);
     }
```

For more examples, I strongly suggest the [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

It's also worth pointing out if you haven't used LINQ before that the processing is deferred, meaning that the iteration over the `query` object doesn't occur until you try to access any of its items, for example, in the `foreach` statement. If the collection or reading from `table` is expensive and you intend to use the results of the query more than once, you can call `ToList()` on `query` to return a more tangible, concrete collection.